# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes and then doesn't detect monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

My computer crashed suddenly while running some heavy tasks (mouse continued showing movement on screen but no reaction).
After forcing restart, none of my monitor ports detects a connected monitor except for one, that does detect the monitor, but not its properties (i.e enables poor resolution only).

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Gnome 3.36.3.

the output of xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me yesterday (literally). Turns out I only had to install the latest NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

Might not be your case, though